# Clicking next on spinner-buttons gives the second value

Tags: webshim

I have a question regarding the spinner-buttons for dates and numbers.

I have an `input` of type number and `min=1` and `max=3`, initially there is no value in the input.
Now if I click on the up arrow (next value), the input shows number 2 instead of, what I would expect, number 1.

This is the same behaviour as shown on [the demo page](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-number.html#min=1&max=3&step=&value=&placeholder=&toFixed=&stepfactor=&calculateWidth=on).

Is there a way to get it to show the first value instead? That is number 1.

Comment: Currently it is not possible. But I will improve this with next version. If you want to keep track you can fill an issue.

Comment: Yes please, but where do I fill in an issue?

Comment: here https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/issues?state=open, but I just fixed this issue in the master branch: http://rawgit.com/aFarkas/webshim/master/demos/demos/cfgs/input-number.html#min=1&max=3

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is now improved. And will be in next release 1.12.8.